# Number-Guessing Game in Rust

Tags: number-guessing-game, rust

I don't yet see a code review for a number-guessing game in Rust. Since I am just learning the language, and since the number-guessing game is part of the official Rust tutorial, I thought it would be beneficial both for me and for this site to open a code review request.

I've started with the [official tutorial](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/guessing-game.html) and then built upon it using the basic language constructs (functions, conditionals, loops) to add some error checking and break common logic into reusable functions.

My background is mostly in C and Java development. This is the final example I've come up with after spending about 5 hours reading the book. What I'm interested to learn is whether I'm using the language's unique features in the expected ways and if I'm re-inventing the wheel in any parts.

```
extern crate rand;

use std::io;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use rand::Rng;

fn read_i32() -> i32 {
    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("Failed to read line.");
        let input: i32 = match input.trim().parse() {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Please input a number.");
                continue;
            },
        };
        return input;
    }
}

fn read_guess(min: i32, max: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut guess: i32;
    loop {
        guess = read_i32();
        if guess < min {
            println!("Please input a number that is at least {}.", min);
        } else if guess > max {
            println!("Please input a number that is no larger than {}.", max);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    guess
}

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");
    let (min, max) = (1, 10);
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(min, max+1);
    loop {
        println!("Please input your guess, between {} and {}.", min, max);
        let guess = read_guess(min, max);
        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less    => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
            Ordering::Equal   => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably expect, there's not much that's crazy about your code. It's pretty straight-forward. There's just a little bit that belies your C and Java background. ^_^

1. There's no need for a mutable `guess` in `read_guess`.
2. There's no need for an `input` variable at all. This also removes the need for an explicit type as it can be inferred from the return type.
3. For a very performance oriented approach, move the string allocation outside of the loop. In the off chance that someone keeps entering invalid numbers, there's no reason to allocate a new string each time.
4. Don't end the `expect` string with punctuation as a colon is automatically added.
5. Add spaces around binary operators
6. Generally, I'd indicate that `min` and `max` are `CONSTANT`s, but doing so may be overkill here, as it would be verbose (`const MIN: i32 = 1`).

```
extern crate rand;

use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use rand::Rng;

fn read_i32() -> i32 {
    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
        input.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read line");
        match input.trim().parse() {
            Ok(n) => return n,
            Err(_) => println!("Please input a number."),
        };
    }
}

fn read_guess(min: i32, max: i32) -> i32 {
    loop {
        let guess = read_i32();
        if guess < min {
            println!("Please input a number that is at least {}.", min);
        } else if guess > max {
            println!("Please input a number that is no larger than {}.", max);
        } else {
            return guess;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");
    let (min, max) = (1, 10);
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(min, max + 1);
    loop {
        println!("Please input your guess, between {} and {}.", min, max);
        let guess = read_guess(min, max);
        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less    => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
            Ordering::Equal   => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            },
        };
    }
}
```

For fun, here's an alternate `read_i32` that didn't end up looking much better:

```
fn read_i32() -> i32 {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line.expect("Failed to read line");
        match line.trim().parse() {
            Ok(n) => return n,
            Err(_) => println!("Please input a number."),
        }
    }
    unreachable!("Ran out of standard input");
}
```

---

> Since everything is immutable unless specified otherwise, what is the purpose of a constant?

A constant can exist outside of a function, while `let` statements must occur inside of one. Additionally, a `const` is likely to be inlined at compile time, while a `static` can have its address taken. [More info is in the book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/const-and-static.html).

> Can you briefly explain when and why I should use the `unreachable` macro?

You should use `unreachable` when the code is unreachable, but the compiler cannot statically verify that. In my example, the compiler cannot know that standard input <strike>will provide data forever or return an `Err` which will cause a panic</strike>.

Actually, thinking about it further, your original code will go into an infinite loop when `/dev/null` is connected to standard in: `cargo run </dev/null`. The version I have will panic and print a marginally helpful error message. Maybe my version is useful after all...

Comment: thank you! your comment #6 took me by surprise (i haven't yet read about constants). since everything is immutable unless specified otherwise, what is the purpose of a constant?

Comment: also, can you briefly explain when and why i should use the `unreachable` macro?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow added some comments